# Flutter BarChart axis labels showing upside down when rotated to 120 degrees

Tags: flutter, charts, bar-chart

I am trying to rotate barChart axis labels to 120 degrees but when these are rotated to 120 degree label text gets upside down as image below[image]

I want to show them like the image below:

[image]

can anyone please give me a solution?

Comment: Which "BarChart" widget are you using?  I found a couple in pub, but neither of them had rotated labels.

Comment: Which package are you using? And did you tried to rotate 300 degrees?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I am using 'charts_flutter: ^0.9.0'

Comment: @aoiTenshi rotate to 300 degrees fixed my problem! thanks you!

Comment: @MoinHashmi nice, looks like the default is actually vertical straight. You can rotate around that.